# Checking link from a host with php

Tags: php, curl

I got a few links, some on rapidshare and some on other uploading hosts.
How can I check if the file on the link is still working?

I tried with curl and file_get_contents.
On some hosts curl is working and on other file_get_contents is working but most won't return page source code so I can't search for the string "Deleted" or something like that.

Is there any way to do this?

EDITED: Here is the new code, still won't work:

```
function curl_download($Url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
$agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

Comment: What is your code? what do they return?

Answer (score 2):

```
function Visit($url){
       $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
       $ch=curl_init();
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
       $page=curl_exec($ch);
       //echo curl_error($ch);
       $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       curl_close($ch);
       if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) return true;
       else return false;
}
if (Visit("http://www.google.com"))
       echo "Website OK"."n";
else
       echo "Website DOWN";
```

Comment: It'll do the job, but it looks a little over the top. [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is definitely the answer though

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Yet, it still won't work.
It doesn't get the source code of some hosts, or it just gets some of the source code.
I must get the whole source in order to search the word "Deleted" or so..

Comment: @user The trick is to look at the HTTP Response code. If the file is gone, the host *should* respond with a 404 code or similar. No need to look at the actual page content. Whether these sites actually behave that way or not is a different question.

Comment: Okay, but it won't respond with 404 if the file is deleted, thats why I'm reading the whole source code.
However, with no success, I edited and wrote my code, it doesn't show the whole source code of some sites.
Any solution?