# Function to search a string into html files

Tags: php, html, string, search

Passing an HTML file, I have to search ALL links inside it and, for
each one, I have to response if it is an existing link or not (as an
URL validator, but for HTML files). I used the function "fsockopen()"
of PHP and it tells me if the URL (HTML links, in my case) still
exists.

My question is the follow: is there a PHP function that allows me to
search every `<a href="...">` of the HTML file, which I pass to it? And
select only the chars of the link (chars contained into the " " of the
tags), so I can pass it into a variable for the URL validator?

Comment: You can probably use [DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) or [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to actually parse the file and isolate only the elements you want. From there you can use [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to filter results. Hopefully this helps a little!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to do this quite easily:-

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.telematica220998.altervista.org/listRicette.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor){
    var_dump($anchor->getAttribute('href'));
    //or whatever you want to do with them.
}
```

Output:-

```
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/tortino_cioccolato_fond.html' (length=67)
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/baci_di_dama.html' (length=56)
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/biscotti_noci_e_nocciole.html' (length=68)
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/krumiri.html' (length=51)
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/torta_meringata_fragole.html' (length=67)
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/torta_pere_cioccolato.html' (length=65)
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/cestini_frutta.html' (length=58)
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/semifreddo_caffe.html' (length=60)
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/rose_del_deserto.html' (length=60)
string 'http://telematica220998.altervista.org/tiramisu.html' (length=52)
string 'http://www.telematica220998.altervista.org/index.html' (length=53)
string 'http://facebook.com/maria.poli.cr' (length=33)
string 'http://fotogrph.com/' (length=20)
string '#' (length=1)
string '#' (length=1)
```

etc.....

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Is there also a condition in PHP like EOF for C++? Or is it useless? Because I have to find all the links in thi web page: http://www.telematica220998.altervista.org/listRicette.html

Comment: This will find all the links in the web page. The first line loads the whole page and the getElementsByTagName() method will return all the elements specified, `<a>`'s in this case. Run the code and look at the output, I cut it short so this wouldn't be too long.

Comment: Now, I understand! ok, it looks quite easy! :)

Comment: I changed it to your URL, I take it that is the output you are looking for? Yes, it is fairly easy, just follow through the docs I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

using wget is much easier for this sort of thing

```
wget --spider --force-html -i page.html
```

You could even run that with PHP and parse the output

using PHP it would look like

```
$output = `wget --spider --force-html -i page.html`
```

or

```
$output = shell_exec("wget --spider --force-html -i page.html");
```

If you need to just JUST php look in to using curl ([Checking link from a host with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555996/checking-link-from-a-host-with-php)) should get you started

Comment: Thank you for your answer....but I have to create a PHP file (it's a project for university). How can I do what you told, in PHP?